# how to read a yes/no data type from access db

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean, ms-access-2007

code below is from `res.aspx.cs`
i was not able to read anything from the field this code line is causing my error:

```
  strStatus = rdr["rStatus"].ToString();
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
                mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
                + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Database.accdb");
                OleDbCommand cmd; OleDbDataReader rdr;
                string strUserId = (string)Session["sUserId"];
                string strStatus;
                string strSql = "SELECT rStatus FROM Reservation WHERE rUserId =" + strUserId
               + " ORDER BY rStatus DESC;";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, mDB);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", OleDbType.Char).Value = strUserId;
                mDB.Open();
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                strStatus = rdr["rStatus"].ToString();
            while (rdr.Read() == true)




                //  string strRStatus = (string)Session["srStatus"];
                //   while (rdr.Read() == true) 

                if (strStatus == "-1")
                {


                    DetailsView1.Visible = false;
                    Label2.Visible = false;
                    btnBuy.Visible = false;
                    DropDownList1.Visible = false;
                    btnCancel.Visible = false;
                    lblReserve.Text = "There is no resevation for user " + Session["sUserId"];

                }
                else
                {
                    lblReserve.Visible = false;
                    Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label2.Visible = true;
                    DetailsView1.Visible = true;
                    btnBuy.Visible = true;
                    DropDownList1.Visible = true;
                    btnCancel.Visible = true;

                }
            }
```

Comment: Don't access the reader BEFORE you have called `Read()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try moving

```
strStatus = rdr["rStatus"].ToString();
```

to after you call

```
rdr.Read()
```

EDIT: 
If you want to read a SQL bit value you can use the method `GetBoolean` on the reader:

```
bool myBoolean;
if (!rdr.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
    myBoolean = rdr.GetBoolean(columnIndex);
```

Comment: doesnt work i am not sure how to declare my variable for strStatus because the data type from database is boolean

Comment: Dear @MalcolmNathanielNg, I added a short snippet on how to read Boolean data using the reader.

Comment: how do i read my column rStatus from res table what is my column index?

Comment: Your column index is 0 since you are only selecting one column.